# C# Linq to Sql How to convert Datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, datetime

I have a asp.net web site.I'm using linq to sql. I will insert to row in mssql database.But it doesn't convert to datetime.I getting a error:

> Error - SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

My code:

```
MyDataContext myData = new MyDataContext();
EVRBA evrbas = new EVRBA();
 string Mydate= DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
 evrbas.EVRAKTARIH =Convert.ToDateTime(Mydate);
  try
        {
            myData.EVRBAs.InsertOnSubmit(evrbas);
            myData.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Change the datetime column in your database to datetime2

Comment: You are converting `DateTime` to `string`, and then `string` back to `DateTime`, what for? And use `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` instead of `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Comment: @Tadej  I writing evrbas.EVRAKTARIH=DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); then I getting error.But I converting adn The problem is getting out of the wayConvert.toDateTime(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));

Comment: @Tadej Why `MM/dd/yyyy`? How will a British computer understand that? Maybe you should advocate for something that all computers understand regardless of region, i.e. `yyyy/MM/dd`. Or, better yet, `.ToString("o")`

Comment: it's returning a bad date value.. is your problem.. not converting a datetime value.

Comment: @EmreAslan Can you add the EVRBA class to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column in database is `datetime` type, then this should work for you.

```
MyDataContext myData = new MyDataContext();
EVRBA evrbas = new EVRBA();
evrbas.EVRAKTARIH =DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
try
{
      myData.EVRBAs.InsertOnSubmit(evrbas);
      myData.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception)
{
      throw;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't working.I getting error:SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Comment: @EmreAslan What is the value of EVRAKTARIH after you set the date?

Comment: @john what is `"o"` format? The only i knew should be good is `"u"` or maybe `"s"`.  @Emre Aslan No, you are not working, thats why you are asking question, haha :)

Comment: 26.04.2017 10:27:42

Comment: @Tadej it's the so-called [round-trip date format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip) (ISO 8601).

Comment: @EmreAslan Are you missing another DateTime that you should be inserting? If you are, DateTime is a struct so it will default to DateTime.MinValue, which is 0001-01-01T00:00:00.00000.

Comment: @EmreAslan Or post your `EVRBA` class in your open post.

Comment: @john MinValue = {-10675199.02:48:05.4775808}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DateTime Mydate= DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Can you please put Break point and check datetime is available or not in the variable?